# Angular JS truncate text and add read more

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that is outputting a number of `<p>`. I would like to truncate the text and add a read more button that expands when you click it.

This is what I have so far:

```
//NG-repeat
<div class="col-xs-4 mbm" ng-repeat="wine in wines">
    <p readMore> {{wine.copy|truncate: textLength }} 
        <a ng-click="changeLength()" class="color3"><strong>More</strong></a>
    </p>
</div>

//NG-click
$scope.changeLength = function() {
    $scope.textLength = 9999;
}
```

I have a custom directive that is able to truncate the length of the string. But when trying trying to modify the text length via and `ng-click` I am finding all the of items in the `ng-repeat` are modified.

Is there a way to change a single `ng-repeat` item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Target the `wine` for the `ng-click`:

```
<p readMore> {{wine.copy|truncate: wine.textLength }} 
    <a ng-click="changeLength(wine)" class="color3"><strong>More</strong></a>
</p>
```

And then only truncate the targeted text:

```
$scope.changeLength = function(wine) {
    wine.textLength = 9999;
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks Davin
Out of interest how does angular know which 'wine' to effect?

Comment: if you look at the generated markup you'll see that ng-repeat is copied on every repeated element. So, there is a new scope for every wine.